# How to add gestures to older programs in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, legacy, gestures

I have a modeling application for a Windows desktop (it will run on Windows 8) that includes a 3D environment. Currently, it can only handle mouse and keyboard input. I have been searching for several days on how to add gestures or touch input to legacy apps, or if it is even possible. If anyone knows where to look, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is the legacy application writing in WinForms, WPF, other?

Comment: Oh wow. That's a question. I will have to find out. I am new to Windows programming and this particular application.

Comment: Why do you have this tagged windows-phone-8?

Comment: I need to get it working on a tablet. I couldn't find any tag closer.

Comment: I have been informed by the resident expert that tcl/tk is used. I hope this information is useful.